# Calling another JFrame in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am trying to create a Menu for a program I am doing.
I want to create a window for the user to choose if he wants to Encrypt or Decrypt.
When either button is pressed, another window will pop up for him to enter the encryption key.
And then the program will proceed to another window where data is displayed/entered etc.

My question is what is considered **best practice** when "calling" different Frames?
Should I make a class for each frame?

I am always trying to avoid using bad practices for efficiency and not learning and getting used to the wrong method.

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: If you care about good and bad practice then consider reading this post [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/928711)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a better UI design I recommend you use jdesktoppane and add JInternalFrames for the various functionalities . That way you can have the whole application in one window instead of creating and disposing jframes

Comment: Yup I ended up using this method! And it makes maintaining my UI easy.